# retrieving value from multi dimensional array by it's index in java

Tags: multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
0  1  2
3  4  5
6  7  8
```

these numbers are indices of this array

this array has been initialized with:

```
1,1  3,1  5,1
1,3  3,3  5,3
1,5  3,5  5,5
```

which these numbers are the coordinate of the grid(the value inside my array). so my question is that,  what should i do if i want to retrieve the value of one cell by it's index, for example if i call a method like getValue(5); the result would be 5,3.
 i know how to get the value in multi dimentional array but i don't know how to get taht with it's index.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yourArray[5]` gives a one dimensional array containing 5 and 3.

Edit: To address your comment.

```
function customIndex(int i) {
    return myArray[Math.floor(i/3)][i%3];
}
```

Comment: hmmmm but i don't have 5 rows right? i mean by calling myArray[5] i think the one dimensional array in row 5 will return, please correct me if i'm wrong. i think myArray[1][2] should give me 5,3 but i want just 1 int to call them like myArray[5].

Comment: You said that those numbers were the indices of your array.

In the situation you're describing, you just need a function like `function customIndex(int i) { return myArray[Math.floor(i/3)][i%3]; }`